# Self propelled mower losing power

Tags: lawn-mower

Bought a new 163-hp Toro personal pace rear-propelled mower in 2016 and it has performed admirably until the last year or so. Very little "umph" going uphill and so-so going downhill.  Have replaced the drive belt (twice) and the drive cable (this year, and adjust it often). Question: does the ability to self propel decrease over time? Time to get a new mower?

Thanks.

Comment: Must have some hills if 163 hp is having problems.  Have you done any maintenance on the engine?  Is the the air filter clean?

Comment: LOL @crip659 Funny, I think that's a model number not a horse power rating!  But you knew that!      Anyway, a "tune up" would probably restore it's previous performance.  That would involve replacing the spark plug, cleaning or replacing the air filter, changing the oil (if not done recently), and maybe even replacing the carburetor (they aren't all that expensive for small engines). I've had to replace carbs on a couple of small 2stroke engines and then they were fine.   Also, be sure to use non-ethanol gas (if you can find it) but at lease be sure to use a fuel stabilizer.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Self propel hay mowers can get up there, but don't think Toro makes them.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit at [mechanics.se].

Comment: The question really is whether the mower is down on power, or if the drive mechanism isn't working right.  Does the mower still cut grass just fine, or does it seem to not have as much power to cut grass either?  Another thought - are the drive tires worn out and just slipping a lot on your ground, which might appear as a lack of drive power?

Comment: @George Anderson...."model number"???? ... how about "163cc" instead of "163 hp"? My typo calling it hp. All other maintenance suggestions had already been (and are) performed, mower cuts grass well (new blade every year) and always starts on first pull. Joe appears to have possibly found the cause. Thanks to all for your comments.

Comment: Unless you hear the engine "groaning" and losing RPM,  it's clearly slippage somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If engine is otherwise running but loses power, it could be worn out cylinder gaskets losing compression.

The gaskets on the cylinder are leaking.

If you want to take look and repair, you can do it, or bring it to a shop.

But before spending that money just do the compression measurement. It is a DIY.

It costs about $10.

[image]

Unscrew the spark plug and screw it in, and give the motor a turn.

If you know the motor specs, you can find the compression it should have.

As general guide: Compression should reach at least 90 PSI if it's hot, and at least 100 PSI if it's cold.

Those motors are smokers anyway, but look for darker exhaust, indicating you are burning oil.

Answer (score 1):

My guess (since I've experienced it and found that many others have as well) is that the plastic counter-lever under the push bar has broken. It's the lever that pulls on the cable when you push on the bar. It's pretty hidden under the left-hand shroud at the top of the handle.

It may look fine but push and pull a bit and you'll likely find a crack... about right for a 2016. That crack keeps it from pulling full force, meaning your belt isn't tightening fully.

It's not an expensive part, and there are YouTube videos on how to replace it by only unbolting the right anchor of the handle. I did it and it wasn't even as bad as the video made it seem.

Not an elegant design... but my Toro has lasted me 17 years and still starts on the first pull, so I can't complain too much.

This video will give you the idea of getting that bar free so you can slip on the new part (but on the left side. It's kinda funny, bc if he had just unbolted the right handle bolt in the body of the mower he could just pull it and that bar would pull out. But maybe that takes more than two minutes... :D You'll want to do it on the left side and not bother with the spring).